# udev pci device rule is not working

Tags: pci, udev, kernel-module

I have a PCI device which have an own drivers (not integrated in Linux kernel). I've collected device information using `udevadm`.

```
udevadm info -a -p /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:0d:02.0
```

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.

A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:0d:02.0':
KERNEL=="0000:0d:02.0"
SUBSYSTEM=="pci"
DRIVER==""
ATTR{irq}=="10"
ATTR{subsystem_vendor}=="0xe1c5"
ATTR{broken_parity_status}=="0"
ATTR{class}=="0x078000"
ATTR{driver_override}=="(null)"
ATTR{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
ATTR{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
ATTR{local_cpus}=="00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,000000ff"
ATTR{device}=="0x9030"
ATTR{enable}=="0"
ATTR{msi_bus}==""
ATTR{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
ATTR{vendor}=="0x10b5"
ATTR{subsystem_device}=="0x0005"
ATTR{numa_node}=="-1"
ATTR{d3cold_allowed}=="1"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0':
KERNELS=="0000:00:1e.0"
SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
DRIVERS==""
ATTRS{irq}=="0"
ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x103c"
ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
ATTRS{class}=="0x060401"
ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
ATTRS{local_cpus}=="00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,000000ff"
ATTRS{device}=="0x244e"
ATTRS{enable}=="1"
ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x304b"
ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="0"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
SUBSYSTEMS==""
DRIVERS==""
```

Then i've create `99-elcus1553.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`:

```
ACTION=="add",SUBSYSTEM=="pci",ATTR{vendor}=="0x10b5",ATTR{device}=="0x9030",RUN+="/home/qmor/elcus-1553driver-linux/trunk/loaddrv"
```

Which contains:

```
/sbin/rmmod tmk1553b
rm /dev/tmk1553b
/sbin/insmod tmk1553b.ko d0=1 t0="TAI" misc=1 
chmod o+rwx /dev/tmk1553b
```

After reboot, I have no `/dev/tmk1553b` device, that means that file rule is not working. What have I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

**0. You're going the wrong way around** with module loading. The rule can be made to work, but it's still the wrong tool for the problem. udev already has built-in methods for auto-loading device driver modules, such as modaliases and modprobe.d; they're *not limited* to in-tree drivers only.

**1. Your shell script is not a script.** The `…/trunk/loaddrv` file must be marked as executable (chmod it to a+x), and it must have the `#!` header telling the kernel what interpreter to use it with – in your case, add `#!/bin/sh` to the top of your script.

**2. It doesn't know where the module is.** You have `insmod tmk1553b.ko`. But where is it supposed to look for that .ko file? Since you didn't specify the full path, it's looking in the "current" directory – which is always `/` for udev-launched programs. In other words, the rule does not do this...

```
cd /home/qmor/elcus-1553driver-linux/trunk
./loaddrv
```

...it does this:

```
cd /
/home/qmor/elcus-1553driver-linux/trunk/loaddrv
```

---

Okay, back to "**0. You're going the wrong way around** with module loading".

- Each device has an automatically generated **[module alias (modalias)](http://people.skolelinux.org/pere/blog/Modalias_strings___a_practical_way_to_map__stuff__to_hardware.html)**. For example:

  ```
  $ cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/modalias
  pci:v00001002d000068E4sv00001043sd00001C92bc03sc00i00
  ```
- And each driver module has a list of matching aliases, as `modinfo` shows:

  ```
  filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon.ko.gz
  description:    ATI Radeon
  alias:          pci:v00001002d000068E4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
  ```
- When a device appears, udev scans `/lib/modules` for any module that has a matching modalias.

So for vendor 0x10b5 model 0x9030, it would be `pci:v000010b5d00009030sv*sd*bc*sc*i*`.

Add these to your modprobe configuration (**`/etc/modprobe.d/tmk1553b.conf`**):

```
alias pci:v000010b5d00009030sv*sd*bc*sc*i* tmk1553b

options tmk1553b d0=1 t0=TAI misc=1

install tmk1553b /sbin/insmod /home/qmor/elcus-1553driver-linux/trunk/tmk1553b.ko
```

(If you write your own module, you'd need the `MODULE_ALIAS("...")` macro.)